# Delete images from media library when user deletes an image from ACF Gallery

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, gallery

When a user deletes an image from the gallery in wp-admin I need it to be deleted from the media library too. I have a function using the `acf/update_value` hook which works uncorrectly. When a user simply updates a post, WordPress removes all images from the media library and current gallery field. Please tell me how to fix it? All the old questions don't work :(

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/type=gallery', 'remove_gallery_images', 10, 3);

function remove_gallery_images($value, $post_id, $field) {
    $images_to_delete = array();
    $old_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['name'], true);
    $old_value = maybe_unserialize($old_value);
    if (!is_array($old_value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $images_to_delete = $old_value;
    } else {
        foreach ($old_value as $image_id) {
            if (!in_array($image_id, $value)) {
                $images_to_delete[] = $image_id;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count($images_to_delete)) {
        foreach ($images_to_delete as $image_id) {
            wp_delete_attachment($image_id, true);
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199907/190895 You can check solution here. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ I've seen this topic, unfortunately, it didn't help me, but thanks!